# Is there any way to filter messages in Slack?

Tags: slack

We're getting going with Slack and have reached the point where having all our productivity shouted back at us from Jira/GitHub/Jenkins is drowning out conversation.  And even the conversation gets in the way of conversation.

I'd love to be able to filter a variety of things:

- filter out all the integrations
- filter out all conversation except for users X, Y, and Z
- filter out everything but user X or integration A

The search box is the frequently recommended solution, but it's better for searching than filtering.

Comment: If you use Slack on Google chrome you should have a look at an extension I developed: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/filter-for-slack-beta/nbhfleeaohlpbahejiladfmpnmggcbpi?hl=fr :)

Comment: If you have too much activity in one channel I'd recommend either creating more channels or using threads more actively.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this Chrome plugin which filters bot messages: [Slack Bot-Filter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/slack-bot-filter/blephhkggdennbfmdcjmlfimedknghfc)

Comment: Is there a solution for those who use Slack as a stand-alone app (an RPM on Linux), not through a browser?